# Stop Keyframes animation from sliding CSS3

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am using this demo http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-image-sprite-animations-with-steps-function to create a CSS3 animation. However, my image is of a different size so I have:

```
<div id="boules"></div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
@keyframes boules{  
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -1067px; }

}

#boules {
  background: url(../images/boules.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  width: 133px;
  height: 108px;
  animation: boules 2s steps(10, end) infinite;
}
```

I want to reproduce the same effect as the example link above but for some reason in my version the frames slide across instead of giving the animation effect of a still image which morphs into a different shape.

I have tried changing the steps, the seconds and positioning of the background but I still get this slide effect instead of an animation. Is this is calculation issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does your image look like theirs? http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/9/9fVQoLD.png

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers aren't correct

If you say that you have 10 steps...

```
animation: boules 2s steps(10, end) infinite;
```

then the offset ...

```
to { background-position: -1067px; }
```

*must* be a number divisible by 10. But 1067 / 10 = 106.7px means your sprites would be a fractional dimension, and this is not possible.

Review what your sprite dimensions are, and check your math.

Comment: Hey thanks for your replies. I think that the problem is that I was not understanding the mathematics behind this. Phlume, if I understand from your post is that the equation should be something along the lines of: `background-width/frame width=number of steps` ?

Comment: Well, better still, the number of steps is the number of different sprites that are in your image. But, since all your sprites should have the same dimension, then the image total dimension should be the size of an sprite multiplied by the number of sprites. And, if it isn't, you have something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works Vals. Thanks for your help. As it turns out number of sprites is the same as the keyframe width but I get your point. Cheers!